# バッチファイル、MS-DOS、コマンドプロンプト、PowerShellについて

Tags: windows

それぞれの位置付けが良く分からないのですが

**Windows10の場合**
・コマンドプロンプト（シェル）と、PowerShellの大きく2種類に分けられる？
・MS-DOSは、コマンドプロンプトの古いバージョンなので、Windows10には搭載されていない？
・バッチファイルは、コマンドプロンプト（シェル）に行わせたい命令列をテキストファイルに記述したもの？
・PowerShellに行わせたい命令列をテキストファイルに記述することは可能？ その場合は何と呼ぶ？？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ・コマンドプロンプト（シェル）と、PowerShellの大きく2種類に分けられる？

Windows 10 に搭載されているコマンドラインインターフェース(CLI)は「コマンドプロンプト」と「PowerShell」の２種類があります。

> ・MS-DOSは、コマンドプロンプトの古いバージョンなので、Windows10には搭載されていない？

これは少し違います。[MS-DOS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) はコマンドプロンプトの古いバージョンではなく、1980年代に作られた独立したオペレーティングシステム(OS)です。

Microsoft は [MS-DOS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) の後に Windows シリーズを開発しましたが、 MS-DOS 時代に作られた多くのソフトウェア資産を Windows 上でそのまま利用できるように MS-DOSとの互換インターフェースを用意しました。それがコマンドプロンプトとなります。(歴史的経緯の詳細などはご自身でお調べになってください)

> ・バッチファイルは、コマンドプロンプト（シェル）に行わせたい命令列をテキストファイルに記述したもの？

バッチファイルは [MS-DOS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) 時代のスクリプト言語で、実行したい命令をテキストファイルに記述したものとなります。 MS-DOS 用のものであるため、コマンドプロンプトで動作可能です。

> ・PowerShellに行わせたい命令列をテキストファイルに記述することは可能？ その場合は何と呼ぶ？？

可能であり、「PowerShellスクリプト」などと呼びます。「PowerShell」はコマンドラインインターフェースの名前でもあり、このスクリプト言語の名前でもあります。

なお Windows 用のスクリプト言語の実行環境としては、PowerShell より以前に Windows Scripting Host(WSH)というものも提供されております。こちらはコマンドラインインターフェースを統合しておりません。また、あまり流行ってはおりませんね…

Comment: 「MS-DOSとの互換インターフェース」という点について。MS-DOSはOSだけれども、コマンドプロンプトはOSではないという理解で合っているでしょうか？ あくまでも、MS-DOSを動作させることが目的のインターフェース？

Comment: DOS ... Disk Operation System。　元はOSでも無くて、俺もOS　と威張ったもの。 OSの範疇は定義によって異なり、メモリ管理まで OSの外側に出された事も歴史的にはあるようです。コマンドプロンプトが OSの一部かどうかは知りませんが、OS機能とのインターフェースである事は確かです。 そして、MS-DOSの頃と、今のコマンドプロンプトは似て非なるもので、MS-DOSとの互換インターフェースの一つでは無いかと思います。 (機能拡張されています) 少なくとも、今の　Windows 64-bit 版では、MS-DOSアプリは動作しません。単に類似のコマンドが使用できるだけです。ただ、多くのコマンドが動作するので、昔から使っている人の多くは、昔のコマンド(の多く)をそのまま、使えます。(コメント訂正失敗したので書き直し)

Comment: MS-DOSは、マイクロソフトのディスクオペレーティングシステムという意味なのですね。よくよく見ると、名称にOSの文字も含まれてますね

Answer (score 1):

> ・MS-DOSは、コマンドプロンプトの古いバージョンなので、Windows10には搭載されていない？
>   ・バッチファイルは、コマンドプロンプト（シェル）に行わせたい命令列をテキストファイルに記述したもの？
>   ・MS-DOSはOSだけれども、コマンドプロンプトはOSではないという理解で合っているでしょうか？

MS-DOSというオペレーティングシステムに`COMMAND.COM`というインタプリタが搭載されていました。`COMMAND.COM`インタプリタが表示するプロンプトのことをコマンドプロンプトと呼び、`COMMAND.COM`インタプリタが解釈するスクリプトのことをバッチファイルと呼びます。

Windows 95 / 98 / MEでは引き続き`COMMAND.COM`インタプリタが使用可能でしたが、Windows NT / 2000 / XP以降については`COMMAND.COM`は削除され`CMD.EXE`に置き換えられました。
`CMD.EXE`は`COMMAND.COM`と互換性を持たせつつ機能拡張しているため、引き続きバッチファイルを実行可能です。

PowerShellはこれらとは全く異なり.NETを用いて再設計されたシェルです。

> ・コマンドプロンプト（シェル）と、PowerShellの大きく2種類に分けられる？

ユーザーとの対話入力（プロンプト）を実現しているのはこの２種類です。

しかし、コマンドプロンプトもPowerShellも対話入力の画面は共通しているという印象を受けるかと思います。実際、あの画面はコマンドプロンプトやPowerShellのものではなく[Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles)と呼ばれるOS機能であり`AllocConsole` API等を呼び出せばどのようなアプリケーションからでも作成可能です。例えばcygwinなどでも利用されています。

またスクリプトに関してはバッチファイル・PowerShellスクリプトだけでなく、VBScript / JScriptも標準で用意されています。それぞれVisual BasicやJavaScriptで記述できます。

Comment: コマンドが具体的に何を指すのか疑問に思っていたのですが、COMMAND.COMというインタプリタを指していたのですね。また、バッチファイルにJScript記述出来ることを知り驚きました。検索してみたら、色々見つかりました